# Conditional probability problem

Tags: probability, self-study

Could someone please help explain how to calculate $P(A)$ given:

$ P(B) = 0.2 $

$P(A|B) = 0.6$

$P(A|{\rm not} \ B) = 0.6$

Any explaination/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $P(A|'B)$?

Comment: @user946850 it is the probability of A given 'Not B'.

Comment: Assuming $P(A|'B)$ means $P(A|{\rm not } \ B)$, then you know that $P(A|B) = P(A|{\rm not } \ B) = .6$. The outcomes $B$ and ${\rm not } \ B$ partition the sample space, so what can you deduce about the unconditional probability, $P(A)$?

Comment: This derivation is called Bayes' theorem. Can you add "homework" as a tag?

Comment: I disagree with Xi'an's statement that this derivation is called Bayes' Theorem.: it is the law of total probability.  Bayes theorem would be involved if the problem asked for $P(B|A)$ which "turns" the conditioning around.  $P(B)$ is playing the part of the prior probability, $P(A|B)$ corresponds to the likelihood, and $P(B|A)$ to the posterior probability, and the Reverend Thomas Bayes gets involved. In this instance, the Reverend is not to blame.

Comment: Hint: Since the probability of $A$ does not depend on $B$, do you even care about knowing the probability of $B$?  If not, then what do you think the probability of $A$ is?

Answer (score 4):

$P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)=P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid B^c)P(B^c)$

Comment: And to continue $$P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid B^c)P(B^c) = 0.6P(B)+0.6(1-P(B))=0.6$$

Comment: @Henry giving away too much I think ...